# SQL Query to Find employees directly linked to manager and have accounts within bank

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to find employees who are supervised by a manager and have accounts in
the bank, displaying the branch address that the employee works in and
the branch address that the account is opened with?

So far far I have this:

NAME TYPE:

```
 CREATE TYPE name_type AS object(
 title varchar2(4), 
 firstname varchar2(20), 
 secondname varchar2(20));
```

ADDRESS TYPE:

```
 CREATE TYPE address_type AS object(
 street varchar2(20),
 city varchar2(20), 
 p_code varchar2(8));
```

BRANCH TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE branches OF branch_type(
branch_ID PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TYPE BRANCH_TYPE AS OBJECT(
branch_id NUMBER(3),
Address ADDRESS_TYPE);
```

EMPLOYEES TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE employees OF employee_Type(
branch_ID PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE type employee_Type AS object(
branch ref branch_type,
emp_id NUMBER(8),
address ADDRESS_TYPE,
name name_type,
supervisor REF EMPLOYEE_TYPE,
position VARCHAR2(20),
salary   NUMBER(5),
ninum    VARCHAR2(8));
```

ACCOUNT TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE account OF account_type(
acc_num PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE type account_type AS object(
branch_id ref branch_Type,
acc_num       NUMBER(8),
acc_type      VARCHAR(20));
```

CUSTOMER TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE customer OF customer_Type
(cust_ID PRIMARY KEY); 

CREATE type customer_Type AS object(
cust_ID NUMBER(8),
address address_type,
name name_type,
ninum VARCHAR2(8));
```

CUSTOMER ACCOUNT TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_account OF cust_acc_type;

CREATE type cust_acc_Type AS object(
acc_num ref account_Type,
cust_id ref customer_Type);
```

And here is the query that I'm using.

```
SELECT          e.name.firstname    as f_name, 
                e.emp_id            as emp_id, 
                m.name.firstname    as manager, 
                e.SUPERVISOR.emp_id as s_id 
FROM            EMPLOYEES   e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES   m   ON  e.SUPERVISOR.emp_id = m.emp_id 
WHERE           e.SUPERVISOR.emp_id IS NOT NULL;
```

The query displays all the employees in the employees table and they're supervisors and the reason I'm also using `is not null` is because is because the bank managers aren't supervised by anyone Such as below:

```
| fname | emp_id | supervisor | s_id |
|-------|--------|------------|------|
| john  | 102    | alison     | 101  |
| chris | 106    | john       | 102  |
| ryan  | 108    | chris      | 106  |
| jack  | 804    | loraine    | 802  |
```

I was thinking of using `ninum` to display employees with accounts in the bank as this column's values will have matching results from the employees table and the customer table.

I know that John and Jack both have account within the bank. although jack has 2 - 1 current account and 1 savings account. but neither will be displays when I run the query.

```
SELECT          e.name.firstname       as f_name, 
                e.BRANCH_ID            as emp_id, 
                m.name.firstname       as manager, 
                e.SUPERVISOR.branch_id as s_id, 
                c.cust_id.cust_id      as cust_id 
FROM            EMPLOYEES           e,
                customer_account    c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES           m   ON  e.SUPERVISOR.branch_id = m.BRANCH_ID 
WHERE           e.SUPERVISOR.branch_id IS NOT NULL 
AND             c.CUST_ID.ninum = e.ninum;
```

But I can't figure out how to use `ninum` to display the branch's address that the employee that work in and the branch address that the account that an employee will have is opened with.

Comment: What is `ADDRESS_TYPE` and `NAME_TYPE` and does the question need `PHONENUMBER_TYPE` or can you remove those columns from this example?

Comment: Please just post some code that will compile without throwing exceptions because it is missing half the details... if this means that you have 3 pages of code then please stop and think about how to write a [MCVE] and strip everything out until you have enough for the core of the question and **nothing** else.

Comment: Ok, so I've `added NAME_TYPE` and `ADDRESS_TYPE` and removed `PHONENUMBER_TYPE`

Comment: Were you able to execute the code? @MT0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.name.firstname                    AS fname,
       e.emp_id,
       e.supervisor.name.firstname         AS manager,
       e.supervisor.emp_id                 AS s_id,
       e.branch.address.street             AS emp_works_at_street,
       e.branch.address.city               AS emp_works_at_city,
       e.branch.address.p_code             AS emp_works_at_pcode,
       ca.acc_num.branch_id.address.street AS acct_at_street,
       ca.acc_num.branch_id.address.city   AS acct_at_city,
       ca.acc_num.branch_id.address.p_code AS acct_at_pcode
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN
       customer_account ca
       ON ( e.ninum = ca.cust_id.ninum )
WHERE  e.supervisor IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This worked!, modified it alittle to include the `cust_id` and the `acc_num`. Again, thanks! :)

Comment: How do I display customers who have more than one set of phone numbers in the nested table? I'm using this query at the moment:

`SELECT t.name.firstname AS fname,
                t.name.secondname     AS sname,
                e.*
FROM customer t,
  TABLE(t.CUST_MOBILES) e
WHERE e.area LIKE '0770%';`

The query displays customers that have 2 phone numbers in the nested table, but the query only displays one phone number for each of the customers retrieved by the query. Am I querying the collection correctly? @MT0

Comment: `SELECT t.name.firstname AS fname,
       t.name.secondname AS sname,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_VALUE, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE ) FROM TABLE( t.cust_mobiles ) ) AS phone_nums
FROM   customer t
WHERE  CARDINALITY( cust_mobiles ) > 1
AND    EXISTS( SELECT 1
               FROM   TABLE( t.cust_mobiles )
               WHERE  COLUMN_VALUE LIKE '0770%' );`

Comment: Do I need to replace `column_value` with the columns I want to match with `0770`?

Because I get `SQL Error: ORA-00904: "COLUMN_VALUE": invalid identifier` @ MT0

Comment: Post a new question with enough information to make a [MCVE] (including sample data and expected results) as the `phonenumber_type` was excluded from this question (since it is unnecessary) and doing this in comments is not appropriate.

Comment: Apologies, but apparently I've reached my question limit @MT0